# Ehcache not able to initialize with the Generic class in java

Tags: java, ehcache, ehcache-3

I have used Ehcache 3 and Declared Cache as:

```
 private Cache<String,GenericClassForList<Person>> personCache;
```

For example:I have many List of object to put in Cache which are coming from database:

```
List<Person> personlist=perDao.getAll();
List<Customer> custList=comDao.getAll();
List<Company> companylist=compDao.getAll();
```

So,i need to put these different kind of List in my cache.So,I tried to make generic class to initialize these list as:

```
package com.cache.cachemanager;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class GenericClassForList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    public GenericClassForList(final Collection<? extends T> c) {
        super(c);
    }


}
```

I am accessing this generic class from here as:

```
    public class CacheHelper {

        private CacheManager cacheManager;

        private Cache<String,GenericClassForList<Person>> personCache;


        public CacheHelper() {

        }

        //initialziing cache
        public void putInCacheFromDb() {
            System.getProperties().setProperty("java -Dnet.sf.ehcache.use.classic.lru", "true");
            cacheManager= CacheManagerBuilder
                    .newCacheManagerBuilder().build();
            cacheManager.init();

           personCache = cacheManager
                    .createCache("cacheOfe", CacheConfigurationBuilder
                            .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                                    String.class,GenericClassForList<Person>.class,
                                    ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(100000)).withExpiry(Expirations.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.of(60000,
                                    TimeUnit.SECONDS))));
        }
}
```

But,at this line of code in `GenericClassForList<Person>.class` as shown below,it is showing me red marker(error):

```
.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                                String.class,GenericClassForList<Person>.class,
```

I am not able to initialize the cache as it shows me:

> Cannot select from parameterized type

Is there any problem in my generic class or how can I make my cache able to identify this generic class?my cache is not giving me to initialize this generic class.

Comment: As the error message says replace  GenericClassForList<Person>.class with GenericClassForList.class

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says replace `GenericClassForList<Person>.class` with `GenericClassForList.class`

Why it's not allowed by the compiler. Because of [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

"Type erasure ensures that no new classes are created for parameterized types; consequently, generics incur no runtime overhead"